# Border drawable for a view in Android with margins on left or right

Tags: android, android-drawable

I need to have a border drawable for a view.. I did it as below. But I also need to have some margins on Left/Right side.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/border_color"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I have tried a bit with inset, but not able to have desired result.

How do I do that?

Comment: If this is a drawable for the view, why not to put the margin on the view instead of on the drawable ?

Comment: why don't you use `android:layout_marginRight` and `android:layout_marginLeft` for your view in layout file?

Comment: I cant put a margin on view. I must have a bottom border such that there is some margin. I have to put a bottom border under TextView (Title of my activity) so as to give a look as if not complete text has bottom border. I can do that by using a view and giving it margin and placing it below TextView. I can set its height to, say 1dp, and that will do. But it creates an extra view. Can I do it via drawable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Insets should work but probably you didn't find the right solution using them. Here is a working example for what you need:

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="16dp"
    android:insetRight="16dp">
    <layer-list>      
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item
            android:left="-2dp"
            android:right="-2dp"
            android:top="-2dp">
            <shape>
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/border_color"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</inset>
```

Comment: nice man!
its work fine here. In my case, I make a master layout with the borders and other, as sublayout with a filled background, sound's good here.